# Can not adding Solution to Sharepoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio

In visual studio I am getting below error while deploying my project to SharePoint site.

**

> Active Deployment Configuration: No Activation Run Pr-Deployment
>   Command:   Skipping deployment step because a pr- deployment command
>   is not specified. Recycle IIS Application Pool:   Skipping application
>   pool recycle because no matching package on the server was found.
>   Retract Solution:   Skipping package retraction because no matching
>   package on the server was found.
>    Add Solution:

**

How can we resolve this problem?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no error, VS is letting you know that you have not configured any post build actions, and that the solution is not installed on the server all ready.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is deployed successfully and i addedd the solution successfully but it took 2 hours for this.